# Send uploaded file data from PHP script to external Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I have a CSV file uploaded to server and handled using PHP file say upload.php.

I want to use data from this CSV file in an external Javascript say "vis.js".

I just need to access the contents of the CSV file, so that I can perform some regex and parse the data.

The PHP script I have is:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
        echo "$fileName upload is complete";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
    }
?>
```

And the Javascript "vis.js" is:

```
function parsetext(data){
    console.log(data);  //where data is the latest file uploaded 
}
```

Comment: php script run on server. js script run on client. do you want run external javascript on server?

Comment: For what you need this? if you want specific value / values from file to frontend you can just parse file in PHP and then send it via REST API to frontend as JSON for example

Comment: Upload the CSV file to the server (outside of the docroot - you should never have Apache/PHP read+write files/dirs available over http). Have a PHP script to which you pass GET vars to retrieve the data you need and use Ajax to access that script from the client (JS).

Comment: Perhaps you should rather do this on the client, _before_ the file is uploaded. (Keyword: FileReader) Otherwise, you will be sending the data from the client to the server, only to then send it all back to the client, before it can then be processed on the client – that doesn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to access a csv file that you are storing on a server you could do something like this with jQuery.

```
function parseCSV(){
    $.get('/path/to/csv', function(result) {
        //result has the contents of the csv file.
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

If you don't actually need the file on your server, depending on your browser support requirements, you could consider reading the file via the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API instead of bothering to upload it.